# How to install and use scikit-learn in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pip, miniconda

Note upfront: I tried following suggestions in other threads, but so far, haven't found anything that helps ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890418/error-installing-scikit-learn), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857322/installing-python-scikit-learn))

I received a pandas file that I would like to run on my machine. In the beginning, the code references the sklearn package.

```
import re
from sklearn.decomposition import FactorAnalysis
from sklearn import svm
```

I do, however, get the following error when running this cell:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.decomposition'
```

I do have the scikit_learn-0.19.0-py3.6.egg-info and sklearn packages in my Python directory, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work. I tried reinstalling it, but both...

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

...and...

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

...don't work. The former crashes my Python (pop-up window telling my it has crashed), the latter produces a bunch of error messages:

```
>pip install scikit-learn
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\programdata\...\lib\site-packages
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\...\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\...\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\...\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\ProgramData\...\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\ProgramData\...\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 666, in _prepare_file
    check_dist_requires_python(dist)
  File "C:\ProgramData\...\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\packaging.py", line 48, in check_dist_requires_python
    feed_parser.feed(metadata)
  File "C:\ProgramData\...\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 175, in feed
    self._input.push(data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\...\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 103, in push
    self._partial.write(data)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'NoneType'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Any idea how I can get it to work? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to pip unistall it and reinstall it ?

Comment: Uninstalling doesn't seem to work, I get multiple error messages. I first have to confirm, that I want to proceed with the de-installation, but then I receive this: PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\...\\lib\\site-packages\\scikit_learn-0.19.0-py3.6.egg-info' -> 'C:\\Users\\...\\pip-0k0t65vd-uninstall\\programdata\\...\\lib\\site-packages\\scikit_learn-0.19.0-py3.6.egg-info'

Comment: How about `pip install --user scikit-learn`

Comment: This tells me the requirement is already satisfied in [path to directory]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

- Managed to roll-back to pip v9 using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839610/attributeerror-module-pip-has-no-attribute-main) thread.
- Uninstalled scikit-learn (which was v0.19). Had to use Admin mode to avoid the PermissionError mentioned before
- Installed it again (which was v0.2)

Code works now, thanks all who contributed.

Answer (score 3):

Try running that last command to upgrade pip first?

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And then install scikitlearn afterwards. And possibly try this depending on what version of python you're using in your environment:

```
pip3 install scikit-learn
```

Comment: And if you get `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:` try to add the `--user` flag

Comment: Upgrading to the new pip worked. Even though it still gave me the old message that I was using the old version: "Successfully installed pip-18.1. You are using pip version 9.0.1...". However, when I try to install scikit-learn now, it tells me "AttributeError: module 'pip' has not attribute 'main'

Comment: Try with sudo before pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: You mean typing sudo in front of it? Doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try iterations of `sudo python3 -m pip install sklearn` What does `pip --version` output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux...

1). download anaconda https://www.anaconda.com/download/#download

2). go to where the file is downloaded and type bash Anaconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

The new anaconda already comes with scikit-learn installed.

If you need an older version of python like I did you can install that version by typing

`conda install python=3.6`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was facing the same problem in windows10 recently for python3 then I try this it worked for me.

```
1.  python -m pip install -U pip setuptools

2.  pip install scikit-learn
```

[image]